# Am I correctly reasoning about cache performance?

Tags: c++, multithreading, x86, cpu-cache, perf

I'm trying to solidify my understanding of data contention and have come up with the following minimal test program. It runs a thread that does some data crunching, and spinlocks on an atomic bool until the thread is done.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <array>

class SideProcessor
{
public:
    SideProcessor()
    : dataArr{}
    {
    };

    void start() {
        processingRequested = true;
    };

    bool isStarted() {
        return processingRequested;
    };

    bool isDone() {
        return !processingRequested;
    };

    void finish() {
        processingRequested = false;
    }

    void run(std::atomic<bool>* exitRequested) {
        while(!(*exitRequested)) {
            // Spin on the flag.
            while(!(isStarted()) && !(*exitRequested)) {
            }
            if (*exitRequested) {
                // If we were asked to spin down, break out of the loop.
                break;
            }

            // Process
            processData();

            // Flag that we're done.
            finish();
        }
    };

private:
    std::atomic<bool> processingRequested;

#ifdef PAD_ALIGNMENT
    std::array<bool, 64> padding;
#endif

    std::array<int, 100> dataArr;

    void processData() {
        // Add 1 to every element a bunch of times.
        std::cout << "Processing data." << std::endl;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 100; ++j) {
                dataArr[j] += 1;
            }
        }
        std::cout << "Done processing." << std::endl;
    };
};

int main() {
    std::atomic<bool> exitRequested;
    exitRequested = false;

    SideProcessor sideProcessor;
    std::thread processThreadObj = std::thread(&SideProcessor::run,
                                       &sideProcessor, &exitRequested);

    // Spinlock while the thread is doing work.
    std::cout << "Starting processing." << std::endl;
    sideProcessor.start();
    while (!(sideProcessor.isDone())) {
    }

    // Spin the thread down.
    std::cout << "Waiting for thread to spin down." << std::endl;
    exitRequested = true;
    processThreadObj.join();

    std::cout << "Done." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I build with -O3 and don't define PAD_ALIGNMENT, I get the following results from Linux perf:

```
142,511,066      cache-references                                              (29.15%)
    142,364      cache-misses              #    0.100 % of all cache refs      (39.33%)
 33,580,965      L1-dcache-load-misses     #    3.40% of all L1-dcache hits    (39.90%)
988,605,337      L1-dcache-loads                                               (40.46%)
279,446,259      L1-dcache-store                                               (40.71%)
    227,713      L1-icache-load-misses                                         (40.71%)
 10,040,733      LLC-loads                                                     (40.71%)
      5,834      LLC-load-misses           #    0.06% of all LL-cache hits     (40.32%)
 40,070,067      LLC-stores                                                    (19.39%)
         94      LLC-store-misses                                              (19.22%)
                                                                                       
0.708704757 seconds time elapsed
```

When I build with PAD_ALIGNMENT, I get the following results:

```
    450,713      cache-references                                              (27.83%)
    124,281      cache-misses              #   27.574 % of all cache refs      (39.29%)
    104,857      L1-dcache-load-misses     #    0.01% of all L1-dcache hits    (42.16%)
714,361,767      L1-dcache-loads                                               (45.02%)
281,140,925      L1-dcache-store                                               (45.83%)
     90,839      L1-icache-load-misses                                         (43.52%)
     11,225      LLC-loads                                                     (40.66%)
      3,685      LLC-load-misses           #   32.83% of all LL-cache hits     (37.80%)
      1,798      LLC-stores                                                    (17.18%)
         76      LLC-store-misses                                              (17.18%)
                                                                                       
0.140602005 seconds time elapsed
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Would I be correct in saying that the huge amount of increased cache references come from missing L1 and having to go to LLC to get the cache line that the other core invalidated? (please correct my terminology if it isn't accurate)
2. I think I understand the increased LLC-loads, but why are there so many more LLC-stores when the data is on the same cache line?

(Edit) Additional information as requested:

```
g++ version:  (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0 
CPU model: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz 
Kernel version: 4.15.0-106-generic
```

processData()'s loop when compiling with `g++ -std=c++14 -pthread -g -O3 -c -fverbose-asm -Wa,-adhln`:

Without PAD_ALIGNMENT:

```
57:main.cpp      ****     void processData() {
58:main.cpp      ****         // Add 1 to every element a bunch of times.
59:main.cpp      ****         std::cout << "Processing data." << std::endl;
60:main.cpp      ****         for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
61:main.cpp      ****             for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 100; ++j) {
62:main.cpp      ****                 dataArr[j] += 1;
409                     .loc 4 62 0
410 0109 83450401       addl    $1, 4(%rbp) #, MEM[(value_type &)this_8(D) + 4]
411                 .LVL32:
412 010d 4183FD01       cmpl    $1, %r13d   #, prolog_loop_niters.140
413 0111 0F841901       je  .L29    #,
413      0000
414 0117 83450801       addl    $1, 8(%rbp) #, MEM[(value_type &)this_8(D) + 4]
415                 .LVL33:
416 011b 4183FD02       cmpl    $2, %r13d   #, prolog_loop_niters.140
417 011f 0F842801       je  .L30    #,
417      0000
418 0125 83450C01       addl    $1, 12(%rbp)    #, MEM[(value_type &)this_8(D) + 4]
419                 .LVL34:
420 0129 BF610000       movl    $97, %edi   #, ivtmp_12
420      00
421                 # main.cpp:61:             for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 100; ++j) {
61:main.cpp      ****                 dataArr[j] += 1;
422                     .loc 4 61 0
423 012e 41BA0300       movl    $3, %r10d   #, j
423      0000
424                 .LVL35:
425                 .L18:
426 0134 31C0           xorl    %eax, %eax  # ivtmp.156
427 0136 31D2           xorl    %edx, %edx  # ivtmp.153
428 0138 0F1F8400       .p2align 4,,10
428      00000000 
429                     .p2align 3
430                 .L20:
431 0140 83C201         addl    $1, %edx    #, ivtmp.153
432                 # main.cpp:62:                 dataArr[j] += 1;
433                     .loc 4 62 0
434 0143 66410F6F       movdqa  (%r14,%rax), %xmm0  # MEM[base: vectp_this.148_118, index: ivtmp.156_48, offset: 0], vect__2
434      0406
435 0149 660FFEC1       paddd   %xmm1, %xmm0    # tmp231, vect__25.150
436 014d 410F2904       movaps  %xmm0, (%r14,%rax)  # vect__25.150, MEM[base: vectp_this.148_118, index: ivtmp.156_48, offse
436      06
437 0152 4883C010       addq    $16, %rax   #, ivtmp.156
438 0156 4439FA         cmpl    %r15d, %edx # bnd.143, ivtmp.153
439 0159 72E5           jb  .L20    #,
440 015b 4429E7         subl    %r12d, %edi # niters_vector_mult_vf.144, ivtmp_12
441 015e 4439E3         cmpl    %r12d, %ebx # niters_vector_mult_vf.144, niters.142
442 0161 438D0422       leal    (%r10,%r12), %eax   #, tmp.145
443 0165 89FA           movl    %edi, %edx  # ivtmp_12, tmp.146
444 0167 7421           je  .L21    #,
445                 .LVL36:
446 0169 89C7           movl    %eax, %edi  # tmp.145, tmp.145
447 016b 8344BD04       addl    $1, 4(%rbp,%rdi,4)  #, MEM[(value_type &)_129 + 4]
447      01
448                 # main.cpp:61:             for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 100; ++j) {
61:main.cpp      ****                 dataArr[j] += 1;
449                     .loc 4 61 0
450 0170 83FA01         cmpl    $1, %edx    #, tmp.146
451 0173 8D7801         leal    1(%rax), %edi   #,
452                 .LVL37:
453 0176 7412           je  .L21    #,
454                 # main.cpp:62:                 dataArr[j] += 1;
455                     .loc 4 62 0
456 0178 8344BD04       addl    $1, 4(%rbp,%rdi,4)  #, MEM[(value_type &)_122 + 4]
456      01
457                 # main.cpp:61:             for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 100; ++j) {
61:main.cpp      ****                 dataArr[j] += 1;
458                     .loc 4 61 0
459 017d 83C002         addl    $2, %eax    #,
460                 .LVL38:
461 0180 83FA02         cmpl    $2, %edx    #, tmp.146
462 0183 7405           je  .L21    #,
463                 # main.cpp:62:                 dataArr[j] += 1;
464                     .loc 4 62 0
465 0185 83448504       addl    $1, 4(%rbp,%rax,4)  #, MEM[(value_type &)_160 + 4]
465      01
466                 .LVL39:
467                 .L21:
468                 .LBE930:
469                 # main.cpp:60:         for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
60:main.cpp      ****             for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 100; ++j) {
470                     .loc 4 60 0
471 018a 83EE01         subl    $1, %esi    #, ivtmp_3
472 018d 0F856DFF       jne .L22    #,
472      FFFF
```

With PAD_ALIGNMENT:

```
57:main.cpp      ****     void processData() {
58:main.cpp      ****         // Add 1 to every element a bunch of times.
59:main.cpp      ****         std::cout << "Processing data." << std::endl;
60:main.cpp      ****         for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
61:main.cpp      ****             for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 100; ++j) {
62:main.cpp      ****                 dataArr[j] += 1;
410                     .loc 4 62 0
411 0109 83454401       addl    $1, 68(%rbp)    #, MEM[(value_type &)this_8(D) + 68]
412                 .LVL32:
413 010d 4183FD01       cmpl    $1, %r13d   #, prolog_loop_niters.140
414 0111 0F841901       je  .L29    #,
414      0000
415 0117 83454801       addl    $1, 72(%rbp)    #, MEM[(value_type &)this_8(D) + 68]
416                 .LVL33:
417 011b 4183FD02       cmpl    $2, %r13d   #, prolog_loop_niters.140
418 011f 0F842801       je  .L30    #,
418      0000
419 0125 83454C01       addl    $1, 76(%rbp)    #, MEM[(value_type &)this_8(D) + 68]
420                 .LVL34:
421 0129 BF610000       movl    $97, %edi   #, ivtmp_12
421      00
422                 # main.cpp:61:             for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 100; ++j) {
61:main.cpp      ****                 dataArr[j] += 1;
423                     .loc 4 61 0
424 012e 41BA0300       movl    $3, %r10d   #, j
424      0000
425                 .LVL35:
426                 .L18:
427 0134 31C0           xorl    %eax, %eax  # ivtmp.156
428 0136 31D2           xorl    %edx, %edx  # ivtmp.153
429 0138 0F1F8400       .p2align 4,,10
429      00000000 
430                     .p2align 3
431                 .L20:
432 0140 83C201         addl    $1, %edx    #, ivtmp.153
433                 # main.cpp:62:                 dataArr[j] += 1;
434                     .loc 4 62 0
435 0143 66410F6F       movdqa  (%r14,%rax), %xmm0  # MEM[base: vectp_this.148_118, index: ivtmp.156_48, offset: 0], vect__2
435      0406
436 0149 660FFEC1       paddd   %xmm1, %xmm0    # tmp231, vect__25.150
437 014d 410F2904       movaps  %xmm0, (%r14,%rax)  # vect__25.150, MEM[base: vectp_this.148_118, index: ivtmp.156_48, offse
437      06
438 0152 4883C010       addq    $16, %rax   #, ivtmp.156
439 0156 4439FA         cmpl    %r15d, %edx # bnd.143, ivtmp.153
440 0159 72E5           jb  .L20    #,
441 015b 4429E7         subl    %r12d, %edi # niters_vector_mult_vf.144, ivtmp_12
442 015e 4439E3         cmpl    %r12d, %ebx # niters_vector_mult_vf.144, niters.142
443 0161 438D0422       leal    (%r10,%r12), %eax   #, tmp.145
444 0165 89FA           movl    %edi, %edx  # ivtmp_12, tmp.146
445 0167 7421           je  .L21    #,
446                 .LVL36:
447 0169 89C7           movl    %eax, %edi  # tmp.145, tmp.145
448 016b 8344BD44       addl    $1, 68(%rbp,%rdi,4) #, MEM[(value_type &)_129 + 68]
448      01
449                 # main.cpp:61:             for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 100; ++j) {
61:main.cpp      ****                 dataArr[j] += 1;
450                     .loc 4 61 0
451 0170 83FA01         cmpl    $1, %edx    #, tmp.146
452 0173 8D7801         leal    1(%rax), %edi   #,
453                 .LVL37:
454 0176 7412           je  .L21    #,
455                 # main.cpp:62:                 dataArr[j] += 1;
456                     .loc 4 62 0
457 0178 8344BD44       addl    $1, 68(%rbp,%rdi,4) #, MEM[(value_type &)_122 + 68]
457      01
458                 # main.cpp:61:             for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 100; ++j) {
61:main.cpp      ****                 dataArr[j] += 1;
459                     .loc 4 61 0
460 017d 83C002         addl    $2, %eax    #,
461                 .LVL38:
462 0180 83FA02         cmpl    $2, %edx    #, tmp.146
463 0183 7405           je  .L21    #,
464                 # main.cpp:62:                 dataArr[j] += 1;
465                     .loc 4 62 0
466 0185 83448544       addl    $1, 68(%rbp,%rax,4) #, MEM[(value_type &)_160 + 68]
466      01
467                 .LVL39:
468                 .L21:
469                 .LBE930:
470                 # main.cpp:60:         for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
60:main.cpp      ****             for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 100; ++j) {
471                     .loc 4 60 0
472 018a 83EE01         subl    $1, %esi    #, ivtmp_3
473 018d 0F856DFF       jne .L22    #,
473      FFFF
```

Comment: It's not clear to me why the number of loads itself (`L1-dcache-loads`) is reduced by more than 20% with `PAD_ALIGNMENT`. Show the assembly code of the loop in `processData` with and without `PAD_ALIGNMENT`. (Maybe the way the compiler has vectorized the loop changed for some reason?). Specify the compiler version, CPU model, and kernel version you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An instance of type `SideProcessor` has the following fields:

```
    std::atomic<bool> processingRequested;
#ifdef PAD_ALIGNMENT
    std::array<bool, 64> padding;
#endif
    std::array<int, 100> dataArr;
```

The size of `processingRequested` is probably one byte. Without `PAD_ALIGNMENT`, the compiler will probably arrange the fields such that the first few elements of `dataArr` are in same 64-byte cache line as `processingRequested`. However, with `PAD_ALIGNMENT`, there will be a 64-byte gap between the two fields, so they the first element of the array and `processingRequested` will be in different cache lines.

Considering the loop in `processData` in isolation, one would expect that all of the 100 elements of the `dataArr` to easily fit in the L1D cache and so the vast majority of accesses should hit in the L1D. However, the main thread reads `processingRequested` in `while (!(sideProcessor.isDone())) { }` concurrently with the processing thread executing the loop in `processData`. Without `PAD_ALIGNMENT`, the main thread wants to read from the same same cache line that the processing thread wants to both read and write. This results in a false sharing situation where the shared cache line repeatedly bounces between the private caches of the two cores on the which the threads are running.

With false sharing between two cores in the same LLC sharing domain, there will be a negligible number of misses by the LLC (it can backstop the requests so they don't go to DRAM), but there will be a lot of read and RFO requests from the two cores. That's why the LLC miss event counts are small.

It appears to me that the compiler has unrolled the loop in `processData` four times and vectorized it using 16-byte SSE instructions. This would explain why the number of stores is close to a quarter of a billion. Without, the number of loads is about a billion, about a quarter of which is from the processing thread and most of the rest are from the main thread. The number of loads executed in `while (!(sideProcessor.isDone())) { }` depends on the time it takes to complete the execution of `processData`. So it makes sense that the number of loads is much smaller in the case of no false sharing (with `PAD_ALIGNMENT`).

In the case without `PAD_ALIGNMENT`, most of the `L1-dcache-load-misses` and `LLC-loads` events are from requests generated by the main thread while most of the `LLC-stores` events are from requests generated by the processing thread. All of these requests are to the line containing `processingRequested`. It makes sense that `LLC-stores` is much larger than `LLC-loads` because the main thread accesses the line more rapidly than the processing thread, so it's more likely that the RFOs miss in the private caches of the core on the processing thread is running. I think also most of the `L1-dcache-load-misses` events represent loads from the main thread to the shared cache line. It looks like only a third of these loads miss in the private L2 cache, which suggests that the line is being prefetched into the L2. This can be verified by disabling the L2 prefetchers and checking whether `L1-dcache-load-misses` is about equal to `LLC-loads`.

Comment: Terminology: *a negligible number of miss to the LLC* - I think you mean ... miss *by* the LLC, or *from*.  Without context, I would have understood missing "to" the LLC as a request that eventually stopped at the LLC (L2 miss, LLC hit).  But as you say, RFOs are not rare, only LLC misses are rare.